# Querying using table-valued parameter

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, table-valued-parameters

I need help please with writing a sproc, it takes a table-valued parameter @Locations, whose Type is defined as follows:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[tvpLocation] AS TABLE(
    [CountryId] [int] NULL,
    [ResortName] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [Ordinal] [int] NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Ordinal] ASC
)WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF)
)
```

@Locations will contain at least 1 row. Each row WILL have a non-null CountryId, and MAY have a non-null ResortName.
Each row will have a unique Ordinal, the first being 0. The combinations of CountryId and ResortName in @Locations will be unique.

The sproc needs to search against the following table structure.

[image]

The image can be seen better by right-clicking it and View Image, or similar depending on your browser.

Now this is where I'm stuck, the sproc should be able to find Tours where:

- The Tour's 1st TourHotel (Ordinal 0)
  has the same CountryId (and ResortName
  if specified) of the 1st row of
  @Locations (Ordinal 0).
- And also if @Locations has > 1 row,
  the Tour must have additional
  TourHotels, ALL of which must be in the
  remaining CountryIds (and ResortNames if specified) of these remaining @Locations rows.

**Edit** This is the code I finally used, based on Anthony Faull's suggestion. Thank you so much Anthony:

```
select distinct T.Id
from tblTour T
join tblTourHotel TH on TH.TourId = T.Id
join tblHotel H ON H.Id = TH.HotelId
JOIN @Locations L ON
    (
        (
            L.Ordinal = 0
            AND TH.Ordinal = 0
        )
        OR
        (
            L.Ordinal > 0
            AND TH.Ordinal > 0
        )
    )
    AND L.CountryId = H.CountryId
    AND
    (
        L.ResortName = H.ResortName
        OR L.ResortName IS NULL
    )
cross apply( select COUNT(TH2.Id) AS [Count] FROM tblTourHotel TH2 where TH2.TourId = TH.TourId ) TourHotelCount
where
TourHotelCount.[Count] = @LocationCount
group by T.Id, T.TourRef, T.Description, T.DepartureDate, T.NumNights, T.DepartureAirportId, T.DestinationAirportId, T.AirlineId, T.FEPrice
having COUNT(distinct TH.Id) = @LocationCount
```

Comment: I don't know about anybody else, but I can't read that.

Comment: The image can be seen better by right-clicking it and View Image, or similar depending on your browser.

Comment: am I right in saying that ordinals don't need to match for Ordinal > 0? Also, that there may be additional TourHotels not contained in @Locations? Finally, if CountryId is never null, and CountryId and ResortName are unique, why is that not include in the table type definition?

Comment: more questions, I'm afraid. Can we have two rows in the @Locations table, one of which is for, say, CountryID 12 with a null resortname, and another also for CountryID but with a set Resortname? Or will these two types of rows never be mixed?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - no, Ordinals > 0 dont need to match. There must NOT be additional TourHotels not contained in @Locations.CountryId will be null when first passed into the sproc, I copy the read-only input param to a new variable and populate that before I get to this problem. Ive not shown it here to try to simplify things, but @Locations actually has a 4th column, CountryName, that the client ASP.NET code populates and I use that to figure out the CountryId - that all works fine. Also, the same CountryId will never be passed in with null and non-null ResortName. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH Matches AS
(
    SELECT TH.TourId, TH.Ordinal
    FROM dbo.tblTourHotel TH
    WHERE EXISTS
    (
        SELECT 1
        FROM dbo.tblHotel H
        JOIN @Locations L ON
            (
                (
                    L.Ordinal = 0
                    AND TH.Ordinal = 0
                )
                OR
                (
                    L.Ordinal > 0
                    AND TH.Ordinal > 0
                )
            )
            AND L.CountryId = H.CountryId
            AND
            (
                L.ResortName = H.ResortName
                OR L.ResortName IS NULL
            )
        WHERE H.Id = TH.HotelId
    )
)
SELECT M.TourId
FROM Matches M
WHERE
(
    NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT 1
        FROM @Locations L
        WHERE L.Ordinal > 0
    )
    OR NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT 1
        FROM dbo.tblTourHotel TH
        WHERE TH.Ordinal > 0
        AND NOT EXISTS
        (
            SELECT 1
            FROM Matches M
            WHERE M.Ordinal = TH.Ordinal
            AND M.TourId = TH.TourId
        )
    )
)
WHERE M.Ordinal = 0
```

Comment: thanks again, I really appreciate you persevering with this, but now the last line 'WHERE M.Ordinal = 0' causes an error 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword WHERE'. Also, just to clarify, it's only necessary for @Locations Ordinal 0 to match TourHotel Ordinal 0, any other rows must match, but not necessarily at the same Ordinal. If it's easier I can zip up the DB for download if you're running SQL Server 2008, or I can arrange you a login to my DB.

Comment: hey, you've helped me sort this out. Thank you so much. That's a great Christmas present as I've been stuck on this for a few days. Based on your last code snippet, I've been able to get this working, code in my first post.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TH.TourId
FROM dbo.tblTourHotel TH
JOIN dbo.tblHotel H on H.Id = TH.HotelId
LEFT JOIN @Locations L
    ON SIGN(L.Ordinal) = SIGN(TH.Ordinal) 
    AND L.CountryId = H.CountryId 
    AND (L.ResortName = H.ResortName OR L.ResortName IS NULL)
GROUP BY TH.TourId
HAVING COUNT(H.CountryId) = COUNT(L.CountryId)
```

Comment: thanks I'll try that as soon as I can get back to my dev computer.

Comment: thanks, this is quite close. I hade to tweak it to say GROUP BY TH.TourID. Only problem I can see now is when I pass in a @Locations with a single row, where both CountryId and ResortName are specified, unwanted Tours are returned that have additional Hotels in other Resorts in the same Country. e.g. I search for UAE + Dubai, but Tours with UAE + Dubai + Abu Dhabi are found, but I only want UAE + Dubai.

Comment: @antmx I've removed DISTINCT from the HAVING clause. See if that works for you.

Comment: this seems better, but when I search for UAE+Dubai plus Malaysia+NULL, I am seeing Tours returned that have only 1 TourHotel in Dubai and none on Malaysia.